# How to swift image base64 encode and solve upload error

Tags: php, swift, image, base64

```
func convertImageToBase64(image: UIImage) -> String {

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let base64String = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options:.lineLength64Characters)

    return base64String!

}// end convertImageToBase64
```

Swift code is here (base 64 encode part) :

```
let base64string = self.convertImageToBase64(image: self.pro_images.image!)
let imgbase64str = base64string.replacingOccurrences(of:"+", with: "%2B")

request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = ("email=\(savedValue!)&image=\(imgbase64str)&subject=\(self.analy_title.text!)&content=\(self.analy_text.text!)")
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, ....
```

php code is here :

```
if($image != "null"){
     if(file_put_contents($upload_path,base64_decode($image))){
```

I want to upload my base64 encode image 
but I can't got original picture.
because picture is not display.
How to solve this problem ?